# Advice on Sizing - Vitus

Tags: bike-fit, gravel

I am relatively new still to cycling in general, I bought a used large frame EMTB earlier this year which was great but clearly too large and I am now selling.

I am looking to purchase a Vitus E-Substance Aluminium Apex Gravel Bike from Wiggle but struggling to decide on size. I put my measurements in on Canyon and they suggest small but the charts on Wiggle/Vitus suggest Medium (different brands I know).

My height is 178 CM and my inside leg is 78 CM

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you'll find "better" information without trying the bike than the website of Vitus. Sizing varies even within a brand.

Comment: As always, its a crap shot buying without trying, but at 178, the small is likely to be too small.

Comment: If you have some reference and basic knowledge of bike fitting you can also use [geometrygeeks](https://geometrygeeks.bike/bike/vitus-e-substance-2021/), for example how the bike compares to Canyon-equivalent sizes or your old bike.

Answer (score 4):

Sizing your bikes small, medium, large, etc, is called *nominal sizing*. The dictionary definition of nominal that applies here is

> (of a quantity or dimension, especially of manufactured articles) stated or expressed but not necessarily corresponding exactly to the real value. (Source: Google)

What does this have to do with anything at all? Well, Vitus has sizes S through XL. Canyon has 2XS through 2XL, which is 7 total sizes. Obviously you won't ever be XL in one brand and XS in another. However, the point is that the nominal sizes might not match up from one brand to the next. I think they frequently do - I think I'm a small in most nominal schemes. However, they don't always, particularly if you're on the edge of one size range.

It is difficult to say which size is correct given just your height and inseam. You might as well take that and reference the Vitus site. You often need some assistance setting up the saddle and handlebar position for your own characteristics, which does mean that a brick and mortar shop can be better for some consumers.

You did not ask, but Wiggle's parent company is in financial difficulty. There is a growing risk that you might not receive your purchase, so be prepared to dispute a charge with your credit card company. I think Wiggle may still be operating normally right now, but the risk does grow with time. Also, the company probably had layoffs and if so, they'll be short staffed.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind taking the time to put your measurements online, maybe consider Best Bike Advice website.  Read the last paragraphs of this page to help you decide if it's something you would like to try.
I hope it helps with deciding bike size and fit.
https://bestbikeadvice.com/int/en/bikefit/